# get file name from blob key in Appengine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, blobstore

In app-engine, given a BlobKey, and nothing but the blob key, how do you get the name of the file that the blob key is pointing to? For instance if the file is `image1.png`. How do I retrieve the **name** of the blob file?

Comment: I had forgotten I asked this question and went on to re-ask it at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26574680/how-to-get-blob-filename-from-blobkey-on-app-engine so I am flagging it for moderator attention.

Answer (score 1):

You can use BlobInfo to retreive instance properties like the filename

```
blob_info = blobstore.BlobInfo.get(your_blobkey)
file_name = blob_info.filename.
```

Docs: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/blobinfoclass#BlobInfo_get

But if you save or upload your blobs in GCS, you do not have a BlobInfo object. More info here: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/fileinfoclass

Comment: I am using java. Do you know how to do this in java?

Comment: In java, `BlobstoreService.getBlobInfos` does not take BlobKey as param.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26574680/how-to-get-blob-filename-from-blobkey-on-app-engine