# How to get blob filename from BlobKey on app-engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, blobstore

This is a server side question. I have a BlobKey and nothing else. How do I get the blob filename from said BlobKey? I know how to get the servingUrl as

```
ServingUrlOptions options = ServingUrlOptions.Builder.withBlobKey(blobKey).secureUrl(false);
String servingUrl = ImagesServiceFactory.getImagesService().getServingUrl(options);
```

But how do I get the filename as saved/shown in `Blob Viewer` as for instance `image_1.png`? I am using Java -- not python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `BlobInfo` class.

```
BlobInfoFactory blobInfoFactory = new BlobInfoFactory();
BlobInfo blobInfo = blobInfoFactory.loadBlobInfo(blobKey);
String fileName = blobInfo.getFilename();
```